# How to get the parent folder of a google docs resource?

Tags: python, gdata, google-docs-api, gdata-api

Using Python gdata in my Goggle App Engine Application I am trying to copy a google docs resource and put the copy in the same folder as the source file. The `CopyResource` method that I use put the copy at the root level.

Would you know how to query Google Docs to have the list of folders/collections in which a file is?

```
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.docs.client
...

doc_service = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient() 
doc_service.ClientLogin('username', 'abc123', 'my app name')

try:
   doc = doc_service.GetResourceById(resourceId)
   newdoc = doc_service.CopyResource(doc, filename)

   # newdoc is copied at the root level of Google Drive
   # need to move it where the source file is located. 

   newdocid = newdoc.id.text.decode('utf-8').split('%3A')[1]

   # would like here to have my newly copied document
   # moved to the same directory as the source one.
   # assuming the source is only in one folder.

except gdata.client.RequestError, inst:
   logging.info('Copy Error: %s', inst.body)
```

Comment: for parent in doc.InCollections(): print Docs.ressource_id_from_href(parent.href)

Comment: Thanks, the for-loop work, though I am not sure what library to import for your Docs.ressource_id_from_href method?

Comment: Copied from here: http://getback.googlecode.com/svn-history/r69/branches/gdata_v3/src/getback_docs.py